# Recording music and Sending it to ftp server using iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Hi 
 I have a plan to develop an iPhone application which records my drum playing sound and uploads it to a ftp server.

I want to know is to possible to upload to ftp server while recording?. Because if i decide to record and save then upload later, there is a chance of memory full. I want to avoid that .

Can i send music files by splitting into small piece ?

Please suggest me any good solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stream the audio to a webserver, written in whatever language you choose.

The server code could then create small files on the FTP server while the recording is still taking place, and possibly even stitch them together after recording is complete.

This is, however, very advanced for a first project, and would make sense to do the 'splitting' on the device before hand (possibly record multiple 10 second tracks), and transmit them to FTP after recording is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Can you tell one thing, how can i convert recorded audio to mp3 or wave?